# how to block users that are not authenticated from specific pages?

Tags: angularjs, authentication

i want to implement an authentication/authorization system in angularjs, i found a couple of tutorials, and a lot of them using $routeChangeStart event and testing for a specific pages, and then ask a service to test if this user is authenticated by sending the token to the api.
and that's what i have done, but i didn't get the results that i need.

## app.js

```
var app = angular.module("KhbyraApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when("/Register", {
        controller: "RegisterController",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/register.html",
        authenticate : false
        })
    .when("/Login", {
        controller: "LoginController",
        templateUrl: "app/views/login.html",
        authenticate: false,
        })
    .when("/Articles", {
        controller: "ArticlesController",
        templateUrl: "app/views/article.html",
        authenticate: true
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Login' });

     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 });

 app.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, AuthService) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        if (next.authenticate) {
           if (!AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
              $location.url("/Login");
       };
    };
});
```

## AuthService.js

```
app.factory('AuthService', function ($http, $q, $window, $cookieStore) {
var factory = {};
var loginUrl = 'http://localhost:2399/Token';
var authUrl = 'http://localhost:2399/Authenticate';
var email;
var token;
factory.Authenticate = function (email, password) {
    console.log("AuthService -" + email);
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var user = {
        email: window.btoa(email),
        password: window.btoa(password)
    };
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: loginUrl,
        data: user
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log("AuthService - " + data);
        token = data.replace('"', '').replace('"', '');
        email = user.email;
        deferred.resolve(token);
        $cookieStore.put('token', token);
        $cookieStore.put('email',user.email);
    }).error(function () {
        deferred.reject();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
factory.Email = email;
factory.Token = token;
factory.isAuthenticated = function () {
    var request = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: authUrl,
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Token '+ $cookieStore.get('email') + ":"+ $cookieStore.get('token') }
         }).then(function () {
           return true;
        }
       ,function () {
           return false;
        });
    };
    return factory;

   });
```

the problem here is in the routeChangeStart even if the AuthService.isAuthenticated() returns true, in the if statements something goes wrong, i think it's about $http returns a promise.

Comment: @llyass Hi llyass have you got a solution for this question, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that the route is loaded even if you're condition fails : Angular doesn't rollback and go back to the previous page. The `RouteChangeStart` event is actually called just after the URL is changed, when angular detects it.. but the redirection has already been made (there is actually no `BeforeRouteChange` event)

So you'll have to handle it yourself depending on your needs. For example, in this case, you'll typically force a redirection to the login page. YOu could also display a login popup on top of your page and wait for the login to be successfull to re-execute the previously failed request (which should now works because you're are now logged again). This behavior is exaclty the one of the [http-auth-interceptor](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth).

See also [angular-app](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app) which implements something similar (based on http-auth-interceptor also)